# Add an custom link to the MODX Evolution DLmenu

Tags: modx

I'm trying to add a custom link to the menu on MODX Evolution by using DLMenu snippet. Menu displays pages, and after the second point I need to add an anchor link on the main page ... is it possible to somehow implement this at the template level, or apply certain filters?

Thanks for the help,
Alexey

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `DLMenu` snippet call. If I understand correctly you need to use `rowTpl`/ `rowHereTpl` parameters, please use chunk here instead INLINE code and specify the next (snippet `If` is used):

```
<li[+classes+]><a href="[+url+]">[+title+]</a></li>
[[if? &is=`[+iteration+]:=:2` &then=`<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>`]]
```